# How to convert jquery's $.post() to plain javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

How do you convert this jquery code to plain JavaScript (i.e. Remove jquery dependency)?

Inside the `<head>` of **app.html**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var textToSend = "blah blah";
   var moreText = "yada yada yada";
   $.post( "process.php", { text1: textToSend, text2: moreText},
      function( data ) {
         alert("Process.php script replies : " + data);
      }
   );
</script>
```

**process.php** is in the same folder on the server.

```
<?php
   print "<p>You said " . $_POST['text1'] . "</p>";
   print "<p>Then you added " . $_POST['text2'] . "</p>";
?>
```

Forgive my newbie vagueness.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doPost()
{
    var textToSend = "blah blah";
   var moreText = "yada yada yada";
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
    else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     alert("Process.php script replies : " + xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","process.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("text1=" + encodeURIComponent(textToSend) + "&text2=" + encodeURIComponent(moreText) );
}
</script>
```

EDIT: I added `encodeURIComponent()` function to encode the parameters.

Comment: You need to URL encode `textToSend` and `moreText`, or it will break if either contain an ampersand.

Comment: @icktoofay Indeed. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 3):

Direct use of [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). Note that jQuery and other AJAX libraries abstract away the task of [finding an appropriate object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Support_in_Internet_Explorer_versions_5.2C_5.5_and_6) to perform the request with.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the $.post, do this:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "textToSend=" + encodeURIComponent(textToSend) + "&moreText=" + encodeURIComponent(moreText);
http.open("POST", "process.php", true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() { alert("Process.php script replies : " + http.responseText); };
http.send(params);
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest object is not available in every browser.

Comment: Increasingly, developers don't support older IE browsers, which is what I guess you mean. Prasad's answer is better if that's a requirement. Most websites I work on redirect the user to a please-upgrade-your-browser message if they hit it using IE 6 or below.